# Regex to detect pattern and remove spaces from that pattern in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, text

I have a file that contains segments that form a word in the following format `<+segment1 segment2 segment3 segment4+>`, what I want to have is an output with all the segments beside each other to form one word (So basically I want to remove the space between the segments and the `<+ +>` sign surronding the segments). So for example:

Input:

```
<+play ing+> <+game s .+>
```

Output:

```
playing games.
```

I tried first detecting the pattern using `\<\+(.*?)\+\>` but I cannot seem to know how to remove the spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this **[Python code](https://tio.run/##Ncy9CsMgGIXhPVfx4aLGIJRuxSY34mJasYJ/fJohuXkrhU7nDA9vOdsnp3vvPpaMDdBOwScLT6BKlGBO8MmJFZRwJlqoIMVK/wStrMfOkCotdJ2ZnDc@Vg@yQDBxfxu4HnBJh/ko7MYl2tF8WUaALEAIH2yk@FTQp8Z@v/cv)**:

```py
import re
line = '<+play ing+> <+game s .+>'
line = re.sub(r'<\+\s*(.*?)\s*\+>', lambda z: z.group(1).replace(" ", ""), line)
print(line)
```

**Results**: `playing games.`

The lambda removes spaces additionally.

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that spaces can be converted to empty strings except when they are preceded by `'>'` *and* are followed by `'<'`. That is, the space in the string `'> <'` is not to be  replaced by an empty string.

You can replace each match of the following regular expression with an empty string:

```
<\+|\+>|(?<!>) | (?!<)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4CbhFK/1)<sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub>[Python code](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsMgEEbh/ZziTzYqE7Lp1pqLZJOCWKExMlpIIHe3dv0@Xr7q@0iP1uKeD6kQT1Sq4InRcv5sF2IK7GA5bLtHwcxuJJJwdiLKrnyv7G692MEZ3NDLYI3qj3/2c/m@dLcTlJrQv4YoS0xVF9PaDw)

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
<\+     # Match '<+'
|       # or
\+>     # Match '<+'
|       # or
(?<!>)  # Negative lookbehind asserts current location is not preceded by '>'
[ ]     # Match a space
|       # or
[ ]     # Match a space
(?!<)   # Negative lookahead asserts current location is not followed by '<'
```

I've placed each space in a character class above so it is visible.